# Logics without or with weakened Universal Generalization?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Are there any well-known/useful logics in which UG fails to hold in full generality? I'm developing a logic that well captures a phenomenon at the level of propositional logic (with no quantifier), but given the axioms, enriching the system with quantifiers cannot retain UG in its full generality. In my opinion, the nice propositional-fragment behaviour should make up for the failure of UG in quantificational fragments, but I was wondering if there have been similar situations to learn from.

Comment: Can you describe some use cases why your invented logic with full compatible PL fragment needs to fail UG when enriching with quantifiers? It's almost by *definition* of the usual universal quantifier's meaning to sanction UG as an inference rule, so it's extremely hard to imagine a case it fails... And does your logic need to be complete and compact?

Comment: @mohottnad, as axioms of the system we have: $\phi=\psi$ when $\phi$ is syntactically identical to $\psi$; $\phi\neq\psi$ when $\phi$ is syntactically distinct from $\psi$. (In effect, the logic conceives propositions as copying the structure of the sentences denoting them.) Now, for any distinct sentential variables $p$ and $q$ the system implies $p\neq q$, but we don't want to say that $\forall p\,\forall q\,(p\neq q)$, simply because $p=p$.

Comment: @mohottnad, Actually, forget about the "phenomenon" that I said my logic captures. Suppose the only axioms are the usual axioms of propositional logic plus the two identity axioms above. The only rule of inference is Modus Ponens. The example above still goes through.

Comment: So your universal quantifier ranges over only propositions with built-in identity as the only predicate in your proprietary object language. Note the identity predicate is really a binary relation, so the [UG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) doesn't really apply here since it needs unary predicate as its premise. Even if your universal quantifier is re-defined to range over all *pairs* of propositions as your domain and you only need one $\forall$ (not two), and then UG in this logic still doesn't hold as you reasoned above. So it seems quantification is useless here.

Comment: By UG we get $\forall p\, (p\neq q)$, and by the second UG we get what I had in mind; so no need to charitably read UG as quantifying over pairs of propositions. Also, I'm not sure if quantification is necessarily "useless" in all such systems. But at least we now know that UG doesn't hold "almost by definition."

Comment: Here to express above closed wff you need to express like $\forall (p,q).p \neq q$ (the objects in your domain should really be pairs of propositions). UG's effect is crucial to prove completeness and compactness theorems, if it no longer holds, then your logic cannot be complete and compact like FOL. Unless you remove all those pairs with syntactic same propositions from the domain, otherwise you cannot pick a *generic* pair to test they're nonequal in the instantiation case...

Comment: In general afaik one case where UG doesn't hold (needs strengthening) is [free logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/). In FL terms might not denote any object in the domain like Pegasus, then UG has to be modified as $Ec \to Ac \vdash \forall x Ax$ where $E$ is an existential predicate introduced in FL...

Comment: And finally if you're not talking about *logic* $L$ but about any general *theory* $T$ in which UG fails, then there're a lot and is the root cause of Godel's first incompleteness theorem. For a theory domain can *vary* for its possible different (non-isomorphic, non-standard) models such as the famous Robinson's Arithmetic Q or PA. For example we cannot simply generalize as $Q \vdash \forall x(0+x=x)$ from a generic natural number having the property $0+n=n$ due to nonstandard numbers may not behave so...